# Trying to compile a class using a custom class causes error CS0246

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, compilation, namespaces

I am struggling with compiling my C# projects from the command line. I've made 2 simple classes to present this problem. I have a `Person` class and a `Registry` class that stores an array of Person. When I try to use csc to compile the Registry file, I get "`Registry.cs(4,5): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Person' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`"

A clunky workaround I found after some time was to compile the `Person.cs` file to a `.dll` file (with `csc /target:library Person.cs`) and then referencing the library file while I try to compile `Registry.cs`(`csc /r:"./Person.dll" /out:test.exe Registry.cs`). This works but doesn't seem like the right workflow at all. If you've encountered anything similar, please help. Below is the source code for both classes.

**Person.cs**

```cs
using System;

namespace ClassTest {

public class Person {
    private string Name {set; get;} 
    private int Age {set; get;}

    public Person(string name, int age) {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }

    public void GetInfo() {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + Age + "\n");
    }
}

}
```

**Registry.cs**

```cs
using System;

namespace ClassTest {

public class Registry {
    Person[] citizens;

    public Registry() {
        citizens = new Person[2];
        citizens[0] = new Person("John", 30);
        citizens[1] = new Person("Mary", 22);
        foreach (Person p in citizens) {
            p.GetInfo();
        }
    }

    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Registry r = new Registry();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I do not see any Namespace declarations, but I am pretty sure the are mandatory? Only things like SharpLab seems to skip them for local classes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750531/basic-question-on-c-sharp-do-i-need-a-namespace Doesn't seem to be mandatory.

Comment: Every answer in the thread you linked says for this thing, you should definitely have one. And it could well be that this compiler is lest robust and can not properly understand that Person means "this projects person class".

Comment: Adding the namespace ClassTest to Person.cs gets rid of the error regarding the Person class. However, now I get the same error but for the namespace ClassTest. "Registry.cs(4,5): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ClassTest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: TestClass must either be in the same namespace, or be using it via a using directive. Mabye the "global" namespace works too, but it is uggly.

Comment: I tried adding the same namespace to both classes, but I still get "Registry.cs(6,15): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Person' does not exist in the namespace 'ClassTest' (are you missing an assembly reference?)". dotnet run works as expected, but csc still returns the above error.

Comment: I think the issues seems to come down to you not compiling a Project - but just a bunch of .cs files. IDE's like visual studio know concepts like having a project, wich consists of many .cs files, wich all have to be seen as one big thing - and all have to be considered for any compilation to work. | In my old Native C++ days, we had to write include orders for every sourcecode file into every one that used it. And we needed special Preprocessor Directives to avoid duplication during the final compilation. It is one of hte many things a IDE will take off you.

Comment: I added 2 Compiler related tags to teh question. Somebody with more detail knowledge is bound to be watching those tags.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could give you a better answer, but the issue seems to come down to you compiling not a project, just a bunch of loose .cs files.

When compiling Registry.cs the compiler has no idea what is in Person.cs, so it can not figure out wich type "Person" you are talking about and wich Functions (including all overloads), Properties and Fields it has. Wich would mean it could not do type checking. Much less put the real IL name for that class into the code, to avoid any mixups. And it will just stop.

> A clunky workaround I found after some time was to compile the Person.cs file to a .dll file (with csc /target:library Person.cs

That is how it works with all those .NET Libraries you referenced, including System.dll. All of those have been pre-compiled wich is why you can use them without having their sourcecode. You can look up their sourcecode online nowadays, but that is not a given. And especially with 3rd party .dll's this is rarely a given.

All I can tell you is how we did it back when I learned Native C++. Instead of usings, we use include. Wich is actually more like adding a reference. We had to include Person.h in every single file using that class. That included Registry.h. But IIRC, also every file using Registry.h. Wich of course would cause duplication in the files using Registry.h, as it got two Person-h - one itself, one from Registery.h's indcludes. The Compiler way past the preprocessor could work this out, but it was slow. As a result every one of our codefiles started and ended with these preprocessor directives:

```
#ifndef CustomIdenfifer
#define CustomIdentifer
//Code
#endif
```

You can see it all over the Library Sorucefiles: https://code.woboq.org/llvm/libcxx/include/string.html

This *somehow* prevented the same included sourcecode being there twice in the end, while still allowing each file individually to compile. Now Visual Studio and the Projecet files somehow get rid of the need to do that manually. You are not working with them, so you have to do it manually.

As for how? I have no idea why. As I said, I only know that out of my old Native C++ days. I have not talked to a Compiler without a GUI for nearly two decades.